# how to get all the tasks that meet a criteria?

Tags: soql, force.com

My query keeps on bombing out saying it's taking too long. i'm running it in the IDE. how do I get this info?

```
SELECT count() from task where type = 'Email' 
SELECT id, ownerid from task where type = 'Email'
```

Comment: Are you a system administrator? If not, sharing is probably causing the problem. You'll have to be more specific than just "all tasks that are emails", such as "all emails in the past 15 days" or some other criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the amount of data you have, this could be really slow. For one thing, you may run into the [50,000 rows returned limit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm). This is true for both queries. It is important to understand that in SOQL, [`count()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_count.htm) actually returns 1 row per record found. So, you can't do a `SELECT` statement that will result in 50001 records returned because it will blow up.

Now, to speed this up, there are a few things you can do. One, you can add more filter criteria in your WHERE clause to [weed out null fields](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_filtering_nulls.htm). Next, you may want to consider using an [special for loop](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm). For instance, try:

```
for(List<Task> tasks:[SELECT id, ownerid from task where type = 'Email']){
    for(Task singleTask:tasks){
        //Logic here
    }
}
```

This will chunk your query up into batches of 200 tasks.

Finally, check out this [blog post about increasing SOQL performance](http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2013/07/maximizing-the-performance-of-force-com-soql-reports-and-list-views.html) and check out the [optimization cheatsheet](http://s3.amazonaws.com/dfc-wiki/en/images/0/0e/Db-query-search-optimization-cheat-sheet.pdf).